3D plot (pgfplots) lookes extremely flat when using transparancy; tips/alternatives?
I'm trying to create a figure of two semi-transparent planes intersecting in pgfplots; however, the results look extremely flat, even though I've cut the overlapping parts into different plots and drawn them in the correct order.
Does anybody have any ideas/tips on how to make this look better (such that it, e.g., becomes apparent where the planes intersect)? Is there a simple way to add a bit of shading? I've also heard of the asymptote package (but never used it). Would this effect be better achieved there (and if so, how)? Thanks in advance!
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width = 70mm,
        height = 65mm,
        view={-70}{15},
        xmin = -1,
        xmax = 1,
        ymin = -1,
        ymax = 1,
        zmin = -1,
        zmax = 1
    ]
        % Draw the axis at the back
        \draw[-stealth, draw=black] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-1);
        \draw[-stealth, draw=black] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
        \draw[-stealth, draw=black] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
        \draw[-stealth, draw=black] (0,0,0) -- (-1,0,0);
        \draw[-stealth, draw=black] (0,0,0) -- (0,-1,0);
        \draw[-stealth, draw=black] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
        % Add the subspace V (top)
        \addplot3 [fill=blue, opacity=0.4] coordinates {(-1,0.5,-0.1667) (-1,0.5,-1) (1,-0.5,-1) (1,-0.5,0.1667)};
        % Add the subspace V (bottom)
        \addplot3 [fill=blue, opacity=0.4] coordinates {(-1,0.5,-0.1667) (-1,0.5,1) (1,-0.5,1) (1,-0.5,0.1667)};
        % Add the subspace A (bottom)
        \addplot3 [fill=red, opacity=0.4] coordinates {(-1,0.5,-0.1667) (-1,-0.3333,-1) (0,-1,-1) (1, -1, -0.3333) (1,-0.5,0.1667)};
        % Add the subspace A (top)
        \addplot3 [fill=red, opacity=0.4] coordinates {(-1,0.5,-0.1667) (-1, 1, 0.3333) (0,1,1) (1,0.3333,1) (1,-0.5,0.1667)};
        
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

 

EDIT:
After doing a bit more research and thanks to @cfr's suggestion, I think asymptote is the way to go; however, I have zero experience, and I find the documentation to be quite sparse. How would one recreate the above in asymptote?

a programme which knows about 3d, especially one which can render effects with a source of light would do a better job than any effect you are reasonably likely to achieve with 2d. (I mean, obviously, you can colour pixel by pixel, so there's a sense in which you can do it in 2d, but you're not, after all, rendering a sunset in oils.) asymptote or gnuplots maybe? after all, you don't need anything super spectacular or realistic - just some sense of depth. in 2d, I guess you need the colours not to simply add so you don't want 0.4 for a plane where it is behind another.

You split the surfaces, but you do not draw them in the correct order.

You're right... thanks, changing does already does a lot to display depth.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=70mm, height=65mm,
view={-70}{15},
xmin=-1, xmax=1,
ymin=-1, ymax=1,
zmin=-1, zmax=1,
]
\draw[-Stealth] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
\draw[-Stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
\addplot3[fill=red, opacity=0.6, semithick] coordinates {(-1,0.5,-0.1667) (-1,0.5,-1) (1,-0.5,-1) (1,-0.5,0.1667)};
\draw[-Stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-1);
\addplot3[fill=cyan, opacity=0.6, semithick] coordinates {(-1, 1, 0.3333) (0,1,1) (1,0.3333,1) (1, -1, -0.3333) (0,-1,-1) (-1,-0.3333,-1)} -- cycle;
\addplot3[fill=red, opacity=0.6, semithick] coordinates {(-1,0.5,-0.1667) (-1,0.5,1) (1,-0.5,1) (1,-0.5,0.1667)};
\draw[-Stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
\draw[-Stealth] (0,0,0) -- (-1,0,0);
\draw[-Stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,-1,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=70mm, height=65mm,
view={-70}{15},
xmin=-1, xmax=1,
ymin=-1, ymax=1,
zmin=-1, zmax=1,
]
\draw[-Stealth] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
\draw[-Stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
\addplot3[
patch, patch type=rectangle, shader=interp, patch refines=3,
colormap/hot, point meta min=-2, point meta max=1,
opacity=0.8,
] coordinates {(-1,0.5,-0.1667) (-1,0.5,-1) (1,-0.5,-1) (1,-0.5,0.1667)};
\draw[-Stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-1);
\addplot3[
patch, shader=interp,
colormap/cool,
opacity=0.8,
] coordinates {
(-1, 1, 0.3333) (0,1,1) (1,0.3333,1)
(-1, 1, 0.3333) (1,0.3333,1) (1, -1, -0.3333)
(-1, 1, 0.3333)  (1, -1, -0.3333) (-1,-0.3333,-1)
(1, -1, -0.3333) (0,-1,-1) (-1,-0.3333,-1)
 };
\addplot3[
patch, patch type=rectangle, shader=interp, patch refines=3,
colormap/hot, point meta min=-2, point meta max=1,
opacity=0.8,
] coordinates {(-1,0.5,-0.1667) (-1,0.5,1) (1,-0.5,1) (1,-0.5,0.1667)};
\draw[-Stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
\draw[-Stealth] (0,0,0) -- (-1,0,0);
\draw[-Stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,-1,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


